# Checkbox in spring-boot table throwing illegalStateException

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I need to get a checkbox inside a table of information. I have the table as so:

```html
<table class="table table-striped" data-toggle="table" data-show-toggle="true" data-classes="table-no-bordered" data-striped="true" data-search="true"  data-show-columns="true" data-pagination="true" style="table-layout: fixed;">
  <thead>
    <th>Carrier Name</th>
    <th>Step 1</th>
    <th>Step 2</th>
    <th>Step 3</th>
    <th>Step 4</th>
    <th>Step 5</th>
    <th>Step 6</th>
    <th>Time to Complete</th>
    <th>Notes</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr th:each="ma,stat : *{marketAccess}">
      <td><p th:text="*{marketAccess[__${stat.index}__].carrierAppointment.parentCompanyCarrier}"></p> </td>
      <td><p th:text="*{marketAccess[__${stat.index}__].carrierAppointment.step1}"></p>
           <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{marketAccess[__${stat.index}__].step1Completed}" th:value="${step1Completed}"/>
          <p style="font-size:12px; display: inline;">Completed?</p><br/>
      
          <!--<td><input type="checkbox"  data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Completed" data-off="Not Completed" data-onstyle="success" th:field="*{marketAccess[__${stat.index}__].step1Completed}"/>-->
          <!--</td>-->
      </td>
      <td>
          <p th:text="*{marketAccess[__${stat.index}__].carrierAppointment.step2}"></p>
          <!--<input type="checkbox" th:field="*{ma.step2Completed}" />-->
      </td>
      <td><p th:text="*{marketAccess[__${stat.index}__].carrierAppointment.step3}"></p>
      </td>
      <td><p th:text="*{marketAccess[__${stat.index}__].carrierAppointment.step4}"></p>
      </td>
      <td><p th:text="*{marketAccess[__${stat.index}__].carrierAppointment.step5}"></p>
      </td>
      <td><p th:text="*{marketAccess[__${stat.index}__].carrierAppointment.step6}"></p>
      </td>
      <td><p th:text="*{marketAccess[__${stat.index}__].carrierAppointment.timeToComplete}"></p></td>
      <td><p th:text="*{marketAccess[__${stat.index}__].carrierAppointment.notes}"></p></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

I was able to get all the table info to show up until I added the check box in. I've been trying different ways. I've tried without the stat.index, I've tried ma instead of market access... none of it works.

This is the error I am getting: 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'marketAccess[0]' available as request attribute

Here is my controller:

```html
    @RequestMapping("/client/{id}/credentialTracker")
    public String getCredTracker(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model model){
        Client client= clientRepository.findById(id);
        List<MarketAccess> marketAccess = marketAccessRepository.findByClient(client);
        model.addAttribute("client", client);
        model.addAttribute("marketAccess", marketAccess);

        return "credentialTracker";
    }
```

Any idea why this is throwing this error and what steps I should take to fix it?